# Add integer value to Powershell as Variable in ELseIf statement

Tags: powershell

```
New-Item "$WorkingFolder\TemporaryReport.txt"
$Users= GC "$WorkingFolder\Master.txt"
foreach ($user in $Users) {
$userobj = $(try {Get-ADUser $user} catch {$Null})
If ($userobj -ne $Null) {
   Write-Host "$User Exists" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Add-Content "$WorkingFolder\TemporaryReport.txt" "$User has been added to the processing file"
   Write-Host "Added to Report" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
} else {
   Write-Host "$User Doesn't Exist" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Add-Content "$WorkingFolder\TemporaryReport.txt" "$User has been removed from the processing file as they do not exist"
   Write-Host "Added to Report" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
}}
```

I have a piece of code that vets AD users that exist and puts them into a notepad document dependent on whether or not they exist. I want to create two variables `$SucessfulUser` and `$UnsuccesfulUser` both with a base value of `0` and each time it is successful `$SucessfulUser` goes up by the value of `1`. And each time its unsuccessful `$UnsuccesfulUser` goes up by the value of `1`. Is there a way for me to do this? So later on I can `Write-Host` the value of `$SucessfulUser` and `$UnsuccesfulUser`.

Comment: "[...] with a base value of 0 and then increase it by 1 if they exist and then increase it by 2 if it exists" - so you want to increment both variables by 3, every time a user is found to exist?

Comment: I have mistyped! I want two variables $SucessfulUser and $UnsuccesfulUser both with a base value of 0 and each time it is sucessful $SucessfulUser goes up by the value of 1. And each time its uncessful $UnsuccesfulUser goes up by the value of 1. Sorry! Then after  I can Write-Host both $SucessfulUser and $UnsuccesfulUser. to see how many were sucessful and unsuccessful!

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense :) You can initialize a local variable by simply assigning to it, eg. `$SuccessfulUser = 0`. To increment the value, use either the unary increment opreator `$SuccessfulUser++` or the compound assignment-addition operator: `$SuccessfulUser += 1`

Comment: Did Mathias's comment answered your question? If so remember you can self-answer your question

Answer (score 0):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72390384/add-integer-value-to-powershell-as-variable-in-elseif-statement#comment127884470_72390384) already commented, if afterwards you want to know how many users in the `Master.txt` file exist and how many do not, you will need two counter variables.

Also, since your code adds `"$User has been removed from the processing file as this user does not exist"` to the 'TemporaryReport.txt' text file, you should capture the successful users in a variable so you can create a (new) Master.txt file with that in which only existing users are present.

Something like:

```
$tempReport = Join-Path -Path $WorkingFolder -ChildPath 'TemporaryReport.txt'
New-Item -Path $tempReport -ItemType File -Force

# initialize two variables
$SucessfulUser = $UnsuccesfulUser = 0
$Users= Get-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $WorkingFolder -ChildPath 'Master.txt')

$newMaster = foreach ($user in $Users) {
    try {
        $userobj = Get-ADUser $user -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "$User Exists" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Add-Content -Path $tempReport -Value "$User has been added to the processing file"
        Write-Host "Added to Report" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Yellow
        # increment the $SucessfulUser variable
        $SucessfulUser++
        # output this user to build the new content for Master.txt
        $User
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "$User Doesn't Exist" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Add-Content -Path $tempReport -Value "$User has been removed from the processing file as this user does not exist"
        Write-Host "Added to Report" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow
        # increment the $UnsuccesfulUser variable
        $UnsuccesfulUser++
    }
}

# Now you can check both variables:

    "Found $SucessfulUser existing users and $UnsuccesfulUser users that do not exist"

# Also, you now have a new list to replace the Master.txt file with so it contains only users that exist

    $newMaster | Set-Content -Path (Join-Path -Path $WorkingFolder -ChildPath 'NewMaster.txt')
```